# Renting in England without local credit history and no previous UK address

Tags: rental

It's been couple of weeks in London and trying to rent a place however getting failed in referencing stage due to no credit check and lack of proof of address, which all has an obvious explanations as I moved in from outside UK.

I might wait to receive my first paycheck to handle local credit check issue but how can I provide a proof of address if I haven't lived in UK before.

Any help?

Comment: What are you doing in the UK?  Working or student?  Can your firm/college help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renting in England without a local credit history](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6189/renting-in-england-without-a-local-credit-history)